# Writing react native android module in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, react-native

React native documentation provides a [Toast Module](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android.html) example written in java.

What does the same example look like in Kotin?
Is there any special steps to configure the android project?

Answer (score 1):

Writing plugins in **Java** or **Kotlin** doesn't have a big difference as both them compile to bytecode.

Mentioning the Github Sample that has created the same sample **Toast module  in kotlin**.

https://github.com/ios122/kotlin-module-sample-for-reactnative

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample with instructions of a react-native application written with Kotlin. Follow the README. https://github.com/ScottPierce/kotlin-react-native

Answer (score 0):

I created a simple `Kotlin`, `Swift` native module example.
[Check Github](https://github.com/mym0404/react-native-native-module-example).

Questions or feedbacks are welcome.